# How to prove a point in a set is an extreme point of the set ?

Tags: convex-analysis, polyhedra

Def: an extreme point of a set $K$ is the point that cannot be expresssed as a convex combination of other points in $K$.

Apart from the definition, what else arguments can we use to prove that a point $x\in K$ is an extreme point of $K$ ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It suffices that there exists a line $\ell$ with $x\in \ell$ such that  $x$ is an extreme point in $\ell\cap K$ (i.e., $x$ is one endpoint of the interval)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks, but I do not agree. Think about points on the surface of a hypercube ?

Comment: @guanglei: You are right. Hagen provides a characterization of a boundary point. What about the following: A point $x$ of a polyhedron $P$ is an extreme point if and only if there exists a half-space $H$ whose intersection with $P$ is exactly the set consisting of $x$ only, ie $H\cap P = \{x\}$?

Comment: Arrgh. $P$ has to be fully dimensional. (Think of a line in $R^3$. Then any intersection with a hyper-plane would fulfill the characterization above)

Answer (score 3):

A sufficient (but not necessary) condition is the existence of a strictly separating hyperplane from the rest of the set. That is, if there exists a direction $d$ such that $d^T(x-y)>0$ for all $y \in K \setminus \{x\}$, then we can conclude $x$ is an extreme point of $K$.

The proof is almost immediate. Suppose $x = \theta y_1 + (1-\theta) y_2$ with $y_1, y_2 \in K \setminus \{x\}$ and $\theta \in (0,1)$, then
$$
0 = d^T(x - (\theta y_1 + (1-\theta) y_2)) = \theta d^T(x - y_1) + (1-\theta)d^T(x - y_2)> 0.
$$
Which is a contradiction.

On the other hand, a necessary (but not sufficient) condition is the the existence of a supporting hyperplane. That is, if $x$ is a extreme point of $K$, it is on the boundary, so by the [supporting hyperplane theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane), there exists a direction $d$ such that $d^T(x-y)\ge 0$ for all $y \in K$.